# Getting filename from server when downloading file from web.api in Angular 8

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi, angular8

I have am getting a file from my web.api (.net core) in my Angular 8 application, but I can't get the file name from the server... If I look at the response in Fiddler, then I can see the filename in the response header (Content-Disposition).

I have the following method in my service:

```
public getAsCsv(taskId: number): Observable<HttpResponse<Blob>> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Blob>(`${this.apiBaseUrl}/getAsCsv/${taskId}`, {
        observe: 'response',
        responseType: 'blob' as 'json'
      });
}
```

In my component I have this code:

```
 public export(taskSmall: TaskSmall) {
    this.taskApiService.getAsCsv(taskSmall.id).subscribe((resp: HttpResponse<Blob>) => {
        console.log(resp.headers.get('Content-Disposition')); // is writing null in the console
        const filename = resp.headers.get('Content-Disposition');
        saveAs(resp.body, filename);
    });
}
```

My web api method look like this:

```
   [HttpGet("getAsCsv/{taskId}")]
    [Authorize(Roles = RoleConstants.Admin)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsCsv(int taskId)
    {
        var result = await _mediator.Send(new GetTaskAsCsvCommand(taskId), CancellationToken.None);

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(result.Value);

        var response = File(byteArray, "application/csv");
        response.FileDownloadName = "something.csv";
        return response;
    }
```

If I try to get the parameter "Content-Type" from the header it show the right value (application/csv).

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE Thanks to @Plochie I ended up doing this:**

API:

```
 [HttpGet("getAsCsv/{taskId}")]
    [Authorize(Roles = RoleConstants.Admin)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsCsv(int taskId)
    {
        var result = await _mediator.Send(new GetTaskAsCsvCommand(taskId), CancellationToken.None);

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(result.Value);

        Response.Headers.Add("x-file-name", "something.csv");
        Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "x-file-name");

        return File(byteArray, "application/csv"); ;
    }
```

Client:

```
    public export(taskSmall: TaskSmall) {
    this.taskApiService.getAsCsv(taskSmall.id).subscribe((resp: HttpResponse<Blob>) => {
        saveAs(resp.body, resp.headers.get('x-file-name'));
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you share the response the API returns?

Comment: You might have not exposed this header while sending response. Your server needs to send Access-Control-Expose-Headers header, so that your custom header is exposed to client.

Comment: @jonrsharpe `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` comes in when you make request from client to server. I think here `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` is needed. Am I making sense?

Comment: @Plochie you're right, thanks; I thought I was on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CORS-safelisted_response_header.

Comment: @NicholasK I have updated the question with my api method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have not exposed this header while sending response. Your server needs to send `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header, so that your header is exposed to client.

Here you can expose `Content-Disposition` header or create your own custom header `x-file-name` with the filename as value and expose this custom header.

Documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers

```cs
[HttpGet("getAsCsv/{taskId}")]
[Authorize(Roles = RoleConstants.Admin)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsCsv(int taskId)
{
   var result = await _mediator.Send(new GetTaskAsCsvCommand(taskId), CancellationToken.None);

   byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(result.Value);

   Response.Headers.Add("x-file-name", "something.csv");
   Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "x-file-name");

   return File(byteArray, "application/csv", "something.csv"); ;
}
```

Comment: I used this: Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition"); And now I am getting: attachment; filename=something.csv; filename*=UTF-8''something.csv. Shall I do some string hacking og can I get the filename easier?

Comment: you can only get the information what you are sending from server. So if you want something custom, add some custom header say `x-file-name` while sending response. add this header in `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` and get this header at front end.

Comment: I have added  Response.Headers.Add("x-file-name", "somethingNew.csv"); and I can see it in the response, but I can't get it in my Angular code: console.log(resp.headers.get('x-file-name'));

Comment: Have you added `HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "x-file-name");` ?